# google map timezone api not working with IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, google-maps

I am trying to get the timezone for a location using latitude and longitude(as requested in the api). It is working with FF and chrome but it is throwing an error in IE(7,8,9)

```
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=43.653226,-79.38318429999998&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=true";

alert(url);

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        cache:false,
        success: function(results){
            alert(results); 
        },
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
            alert(thrownError);
        },
        fail: function(){
            alert('ajax fail');
        }
    });
```

Error shows "No Transport"

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XDR-object of InternetExplorer currently is not supported by jQuery, you'll need  a plugin like [**jquery.xdomain.js**](https://gist.github.com/1114981)

But there is another issue: the timezone-API requires the HTTPS-protocoll , when the document that requests the API doesn't use HTTPS, it will still fail in IE.

But you may use a serverside proxy-script that fetches the result from the timezone-API and delivers it to jQuery